# How to troubleshoot jupyter lab http://localhost:888/api/kernels?403 (Forbidden)

Tags: jupyter-lab

Today, I was going to continue working on a remote notebook that I was working on yesterday. However, now the notebook (JupyterLab 3.0.9) will not load. Upon reload I get a password request, which is quite unusual to get every time and the Chrome console shows:

> jupyter lab http://localhost:888/api/kernels?403 (Forbidden)

for many different components. Any idea what could have caused this behavior?

I restarted the remote server and now it works. But is unclear to me what happend.

[image]